# fadeIn not working for first open page with jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein

iam beginner. so i need your help for jquery.
i have exist code, i use fadeIn to show element. but its not working

```
window.onload = function()
{
    let inp_findStock_Id = $('#inp_findStock_Id');
    let coba = getQueryVariable("search");
    inp_findStock_Id.val(coba);
    // inp_findStock_Id.preventDefault(); // if add this code, fadeIn can running, but ajx_findStock can not running automaticly.
    ajx_findStock();
    $('#tblAjax').fadeIn(800);
    inp_findStock_Id.select();
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    let query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    let parms = query.split('&');
    for (let i = 0; i < parms.length; i++) {
        let pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0 && variable === parms[i].substring(0, pos)) {
            return parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element `$('#tblAjax')` must first be set to `display: none;`, otherwise the fading effect will not work on a currently displayed element.

**With Display *not* set:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.box').fadeIn(800);
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: #222;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">display: auto</div>
```

**With Display set to *none*:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.box').fadeIn(800);
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: #222;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">display: none</div>
```

Comment: i have done, but fadeIn can not running for first open page.

Comment: @Hamputera Try putting the `$('#tblAjax').fadeIn(800);)` line at the beginning of the onload function.